# How can i invert UIImageView?

Tags: ios, uiimageview

Hy everybody!
I load black and white image to `UIImageView` and i don't know how can i invert the colors with a button.

I load the image with this code:

```
ImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
```

Anyone know that?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try playing with differnt blend modes in the UIImage method:

```
- (void)drawAtPoint:(CGPoint)point blendMode:(CGBlendMode)blendMode alpha:(CGFloat)alpha
```

I haven't actually used it but maybe one of the modes will give you the result you need.